# Вывод данных по запросу в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, вывод

Есть четыре функции, каждая строит определённый график.
Подскажите, как вызвать эти функции по запросу пользователя?

Comment: да хотя бы через if

Answer (score 2):

Используйте словари

```
def f1():
    return 1

def f2():
    return 2

def f3():
    return 3

def f4():
    return 4

dict_ = {
    "f1": f1,
    "f2": f2,
    "f3": f3,
    "f4": f4
}

inp = input()
print(dict_[inp]())
```

Answer (score 1):

если **творить дичь** с опасным кодом, то можно так:

```
def func1():
    return 1

try:
    name = input()
    print(eval(name)())
except:
    pass
```

если творить меньшую дичь, то

```
import foo

def func1():
    return 1

func = getattr(foo, input())
print(func())
```

Comment: [ _**ОПАСНЫЙ КОД**_ ] особенно это хорошо для пони: `(lambda:os.system("rm -rf /")` ;D